# How can I check if a comment is "internal" using YouTrack Workflow Builder?

Tags: workflow, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

In YouTrack I would like to change the status if a team member replies to a ticket -> this works great.

But now I would like to check if the comment was internal, then the status should not be changed.

Does anyone have an idea how to? In Workflow Builder I don't see a condition like "if comment is internal".

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the normal non-helpdesk projects, there is no "public" or "private" comment, all comments have visibility restricts and can be shown to these or those users and groups. That's why I believe that checking the visibility has more sense. I recommend you check the `permittedGroups` and `permittedUsers` properties: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/v1-IssueComment.html#properties

I also wish to add that checking the comment visibility settings is available in the JS Workflows only and at the moment is not implemented in the Visual Constructor.